# Should I be able to review tag-wiki edits, if I can't make them?

Tags: support

Suggested edits to tag wikis appear in my review queue on the site.

However, if I go to edit a tag wiki (excerpt in this case), that also goes into a queue.

Is it a mistake that I'm able to review actions that I can't actually perform? Or is it a case of multiple-people review, so one person making a mistake doesn't matter?

Comment: I think you've got it with your latter point. You're reputable enough to be able to decide about things like that *along with other people*, but not yet reputable enough to be able to do it all by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag Wiki edit approval *is* a privilege you can perform, though. That unlocks at 5,000 reputation (which you are in excess of).

I think you're conflating it with the ability to make Tag Wiki edits **without approval**, which requires Trusted Member status/20,000 reputation.